# How to handle different sizes of screen on android

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen

First, I run program on emulator. After that, I run on many android phones. Some are very small, some are show in rotate side then can't rotate back, and can't scroll (I did not do that), some are OK.

I understand may caused by different types of screen and I used AbsoluteLayout, but I do not know how to solve that problem.So, I need to resolve this problem. Anyone can help? Thanks ka

Example page that I did:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usrname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="21px"
    android:layout_x="105px"
    android:layout_y="179px"
    android:text="Username :"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/usrname_text"
    android:layout_width="161px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="74px"
    android:layout_y="206px"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="105px"
    android:layout_y="252px"
    android:text="Password :"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pass_text"
    android:layout_width="163px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="73px"
    android:layout_y="279px"
    android:password="true"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="73px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="75px"
    android:layout_y="333px"
    android:text="Login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancle"
    android:layout_width="73px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="157px"
    android:layout_y="333px"
    android:text="Cancel" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

These are pictures from Galaxy-S and emulator :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fo rthis problem u use Support screens tag in manifestfile.For further reference see the below link [Support screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I tried --> android:anyDensity = "true", android:normalScreen = "true" but nothing change.

Answer (score 3):

The developer docs have lots of good guidance about this in the article on [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Under the Best Practices section, they recommend not using AbsoluteLayout. If you share what you are trying to accomplish, we may be able to suggest a way that works on a wide range of screens.

Comment: I don't know if I not use Absolute layout, what other layouts should I be use.

Comment: I see that you posted some pictures. It looks like a vertical LinearLayout can work for most of it. When it comes to the two buttons, they can be in a horizontal LinearLayout that is added to the vertical one. Another approach would be to use a RelativeLayout for everything. It's a little harder to learn to use, but can often avoid nested layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Really think you should look at relative layouts, esp if you are starting with android now. Its a little harder, since you cant give absolute coordinates for any of your items, but you position your items with respect to one another. After that you dont need to worry abt different screen sizes.